# How to bind a dynamic @Named binding

Tags: guice

I'd like to create a configurable Module that will bind a few different @Named things.  Applications/injections that use the module will know the @Name ahead of time, but the module itself won't know until it's instantiated at runtime.

I'm using kotlin in my example code, but happy for java answers.

This fails to compile because all of the @Named annotations need to refer to constant strings, not runtime variables (`An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant`):

```
class DbModule(val configPath: String) : KotlinModule() {
    @Provides
    @Named(configPath) // <-- can't do this
    fun provideDbConfig(loader: ConfigLoader): DbConfig { 
         // note ConfigLoader is separately bound, 
         // but a needed depenency of DbConfig
         return DbConfig(loader, configPath)
    }

    @Provides
    @Named(configPath) // <-- can't do this
    fun provideDataSource(
        @Named(configPath)  // <-- can't do this
        dbConfig: DbConfig): DataSource  
    {
        return dbConfig.dataSource
    }
}
```

I can get the DbConfig binding to work by adding a Provider:

```
private class ConfigProvider
@Inject constructor(
    val loader: ConfigLoader,
    @Named("configPath") val configPath: String
) : Provider<DbConfig> {
    override fun get(): DbConfig {
        return DbConfig(loader, configPath)
    }
}

class DbModule(val configPath: String) : KotlinModule() {
    override configure() {
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("configPath"))
            .to(configPath)
        bind<DbConfig>().annotatedWith(Names.named(configPath))
            .toProvider(ConfigProvider::class.java)

    }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to get a `Provider<DataSource>` that would have the correct `configPath` annotated `DbConfig()` available to it so that it can get the `DataSource` out of the config?  I might be able to have a `DataSourceProvider` that constructs its own `DbConfig(configPath)` the same way the `ConfigProvider` does, but it seems preferable to have guice create the dbconfig via the `ConfigProvider` and be able to leverage that in the `DataSourceProvider`?

At the end of this, I'd like to be able to have the following injected:

```
class BusinessObject1
    @Inject constructor(
        @Named("secondaryDb") val dbConfig: DbConfig
    )
class BusinessObject2
    @Inject constructor(
        @Named("secondaryDb") val dataSource: DataSource
    )
```

Assuming that those objects are created by an injector:

```
Guice.createInjector(DbModule("secondaryDb"))
```

(also note the code above won't allow creation of both `DbModule("secondaryDb")` and `DbModule("tertiaryDb")`, but that can be solved with private modules, which I've left to avoid additional complexity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've left aside [PrivateModule](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/4.2.2/javadoc/com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html), but that's exactly what I'd use to solve your problem. If I've guessed your KotlinModule source correctly, it has a counterpart in [KotlinPrivateModule](https://github.com/authzee/kotlin-guice/blob/master/kotlin-guice/src/main/kotlin/com/authzee/kotlinguice4/KotlinPrivateModule.kt).

Guice docs advocate for this solution as the "robot legs problem" (imagine binding left and right legs with identical thighs, knees, and shins, but different left and right legs) in its FAQ as the question ["How do I build two similar but slightly different trees of objects?"](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how-do-i-build-two-similar-but-slightly-different-trees-of-objects).

In Java this would look like:

```java
public class DbModule extends PrivateModule {
  private final String configPath;

  public DbModule(String configPath) { this.configPath = configPath; }

  // (no @Named annotation; bind it like it's the only one!)
  @Provides DbConfig provideDbConfig(ConfigLoader loader) { 
    return new DbConfig(loader, configPath);
  }

  // (no @Named annotation; bind it like it's the only one!)
  @Provides DataSource provideDataSource(DbConfig dbConfig) {
    return dbConfig.dataSource;
  }

  @Override public void configure() {
    // now bind the unqualified one to the qualified one
    bind(DbConfig.class).annotatedWith(Names.named(configPath)).to(DbConfig.class);
    bind(DataSource.class).annotatedWith(Names.named(configPath)).to(DataSource.class);

    // and now you can expose only the qualified ones
    expose(DbConfig.class).annotatedWith(Names.named(configPath));
    expose(DataSource.class).annotatedWith(Names.named(configPath));
  }
}
```

This way your `@Provides` methods don't need to try to use an annotation that is only available at runtime, and you don't clutter the global Injector with unqualified DbConfig and DataSource binding. Futhermore—and this is the real benefit to the solution—within DbModule you can inject DbConfig and DataSource directly without `@Named` annotations. This makes it much easier to produce and consume reusable machinery, since your reusable pieces won't have any `@Named` annotations to worry about. You could even bind your config path as a String (`@Named("configPath") String` or `@ConfigPath String`) and have that directly injectable into DbConfig, allowing you to mark DbConfig with `@Inject` and get rid of its `@Provides` method.

(For what it's worth, if you had gone with an alternate solution that doesn't use PrivateModules and instead used longer and more-complex `bind` statements with `Names.named`, then `DbModule("secondaryDb")` and `DbModule("tertiaryDb")` would coexist just fine as long as the public bindings don't conflict with one another.)

Comment: Interesting.  I had originally tried something very similar to that, but it failed to work when there was also an unqualified instance of the @Provided classes.  So it seems like while the private module prevents the global injector from seeing the unqualified bindings within itself, it sees globally unqualfied bindings and detects conflicts there?  The error I get is: `A binding to DbConfig was already configured at GlobalDbModule().provideDbConfig() at PrivateDbModule.provideDbConfig()`

Comment: @Joe That's correct. The private module has access to everything public, so you'll get a conflicting binding error if anything within the PrivateModule conflicts with anything public; Guice won't override it. Personally I would recommend against defining a global DbConfig if you have multiple other (qualified) DbConfig instances bouncing around your Injector, since that would make your setup much less intuitive to read, but as a second choice you could always use a qualifier annotation (`@PerDbModule`?) to distinguish between the global DbConfig and each DbConfig you bind in DbModule.